# no activity found to handle

Tags: android, permissions, call

**I am getting error while click on list item**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String selected =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.no)).getText().toString();
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    try {
                        Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(selected));
                        startActivity(in);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION","PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
                    }
}
```

**An error is Message which i am getting  in Logcat**

```
01-06 10:37:19.091 19537-19537/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication, PID: 19537
                                                   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=1234 567 89 }
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1856)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1552)
```

***Manifest file here i have added permission and MainActivity and intent filter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: At least post your problem or logcat.

Comment: If permission problem add "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>"

Comment: Make sure activity is added in manifest

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=1234 567 89 }

All activities must be declared in the **`AndroidManifest.xml`**. Without the declaration, `ActivityNotFoundException` is thrown.

### Make sure activity is added in AndroidManifest  & `Intent.ACTION_CALL` calling properly .

You can share your ***manifest*** .
Did you add this ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: No it is a problem with on click, if i remove intent, it is working fine.

Comment: @SairamkrishnaMammahe Okay okay .Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

You can try (your selected text must be format: tel:xxxxxxxxx)

```
 Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(selected));
                    startActivity(in);
```

Remember add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all since you are using implicit intent , you do not need to specify call permission in manifest.

Whenever you are calling any implicit intent if it doesn't find any matching activity which can perform given action , then this exception occurs.
You can handle that by using following code.

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(selected));
  List<ResolveInfo> list=new  PackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent ,0);
  if(list.size()>0){
   Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");
   startActivity(chooser);
  }else{
  //Show toast or alert saying no activities available to perform specified action.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is to make Phone Call data format is like this `tel:your_number` :)

```
 Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+selected));
```